# Sliders cursor move in increments

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a range slider. When you drag the sliderCursor, I want it to move in increments of 10.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var cursorPosition = clamp01((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention);
sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (((1 - cursorPosition) * sliderDimention) - cursorRadius) + 'px)';
```

I tried adding 10 to `cursorPosition`, but it didn't still didn't move in increments. How can I make the sliderCursor move in increments?

#### JSFiddle

```js
function RangeSlider( /** DOM Elem */ parentElem) {
  var wrapperElem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperElem')[0],
    slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0],
    sliderCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderCursor')[0];

  var sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth,
    cursorRadius = sliderCursor.offsetHeight / 2,
    startPoint,
    currentTarget;


  function sliderDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    currentTarget = null;
    var sliderWithDescendents = wrapperElem.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderWithDescendents.length; i++) {
      sliderWithDescendents[i]
      if (sliderWithDescendents[i] === e.target || wrapperElem === e.target) {
        currentTarget = wrapperElem.children[0];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (currentTarget === null) return;

    startPoint = getOrigin(currentTarget);
    sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
    sliderMove(e);
  }

  function sliderMove(e) {
    var cursorPosition = clamp01((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention);
    sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (((1 - cursorPosition) * sliderDimention) - cursorRadius) + 'px)';
  }

  function mouseUpEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
  }
  wrapperElem.addEventListener('mousedown', sliderDown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvents);
}

var sliderTest = document.getElementById('sliderTest');
var test = new RangeSlider(sliderTest);






function clamp01(val) {
  return Math.min(1, Math.max(0, val));
}

function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
.wrapperElem {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 62px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sliderCursor {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperElem">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderCursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of that could be done in increments of 10 with the modulus.

(I don't know your variables well, so I just used random ones. Sorry.)

```
if(cursorPosition % 10 == 0){sliderPosition = cursorPosition};
```

So every time cursorPosition is a multiple of 10, sliderPosition will increment.

Answer (score 0):

You can really simplify everything by using JQueryUI, see here https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/7ku7qvfx/18/

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">increments of 10:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:0,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step: 10,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm trying to create my own for learning purposes with vanilla JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the perfect answer for you!

Create two sliders that are exact copies of each other (the ranges can be anything):

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="sliderOne" id="sliderOne">
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="sliderTwo" id="sliderTwo">
```

Now create the css for them so both are in the same spot and are the same size, but make the second slider invisible:

```
.sliderOne, .sliderTwo {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25vh;
  height: 4vh;
  border-radius: 5vh;
  background: rgb(255, 128, 64);
  top: 65%;
  left: 13.75%;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.sliderOne::-webkit-slider-thumb, .sliderTwo::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 3.5vh;
  height: 3.5vh;
  border-radius: 5vh; 
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sliderTwo, .sliderTwo::-webkit-slider-thumb
{
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0) /* The fourth zero is opacity */
}
```

Then, just create an event listener to tell if the slider has been changed (I'm doing this in javascript, but the listener could be within the .html file):

```
document.getElementById("sliderTwo").addEventListener("input", function() {
  if(this.value%10 === 0) {
    document.getElementById('scalePer').innerHTML= ''+this.value+'%'; 
    document.getElementById('scaleSlider').value = this.value;
  }
})
    document.getElementById("sliderTwo").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if(this.value%10 === 0) {
    document.getElementById('scalePer').innerHTML= ''+this.value+'%'; 
    document.getElementById('scaleSlider').value = this.value;
  }
})
```

Now it will only increment the shown slider if the value is a multiple of ten.

I think this works like so, because the invisible slider is on top of the shown slider, and that is why it updates in increments.